# Upload file on root path Wordpress Multisite of subsite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

What I whant is too simple :

I have a multisite wordpress site : mynetwork.com

Inside it, I have two sites on separate domaine : myblog.com & myportfolio.com

Now, what I want to know is how to upload file to be accessible on only myblog.com/test.json, in others words, I wanna this :

```
GET mynetwork.com/test.json : 404/NOT FOUND
GET myblog.com/test.json : 302/FOUND
GET myportfolio.com/test.json : 404/NOT FOUND
```

How do I do it ?

Comment: In multisite there is only one root  directory. If you want only one url to have this file you have two options htacess or nginx configuration or creation of a virtual page to serve the JSON. Why does it need to be on the root?

Comment: I need to upload sw.js and manifest.json to serve Push notification ads but the site I want to serve thoses files belongs to a wordpress network site. There's a technique or plugin I can use ? Or I must do it myself ?

Comment: There are plugins you can use, search PWA

Comment: Thank you @JordanCauley but it isn't to create PWA version of the site !

Comment: My untested hunch: put it in the multisite root, and use .htaccess redirect rules or similar to block access on the sites you don't want. (Or maybe the reverse? Use a redirect for just the site you want?)

Comment: I have the same problem, I need to put an ads.txt file in the root of each site of a multisite